# Is it's possible to generate WASM file instead of bundle.js?

Tags: webassembly

As far as I understand WASM is very closely by desing to MSIL, but designed to work in browsers. So it's low-level representation of code.

Can I generate WASM code and connect it to page instead of generating minificated version of js-bundle like bundle.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point in time, WebAssembly isn't a suitable replacement for JavaScript. It simply isn't a design goal to replace JavaScript. It can replace some usescases which JavaScript met, such as asm.js, but minified and bundled logic to manipulate the DOM isn't well suited for WebAssembly.

In fact, WebAssembly has no way to directly access Web APIs such as those to manipulate DOM, touch canvas, handle input events, etc. This [may change in the future](http://webassembly.org/docs/gc/).

From your question it sounds like you're using JavaScript in its "traditional" usecase: write an application which interfaces with the user. Unless you had code in a language such as C++, it's unlikely that using WebAssembly will be profitable to you in the near to medium term. Even long term, JavaScript is very well suited for that purpose. Packaging and compression help it overcome some of its transfer overheads.

That being said, you could write an entire application in WebAssembly and connect it to JavaScript imports to interact with the user. It probably isn't a great idea for the reasons stated above.